# Convert Object to List in java

Tags: java, casting, gson, objectmapper

I have a object/string in the format `{"String one", "String two" }` How can i cast this to java `Collection`.

Tried this but did not work -

```
om.readValue(str, new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){});
```

Note: the String does not have [] (brackets) at the start and the end to be treated as array.

Comment: `{"String one", "String two" }` this is not valid JSON by the way. Did you mean?: `["String one", "String two" ]`

Comment: its not a json, But my program needs to convert object of that type to list of strings.

Comment: It's not about your needs. Gson (or Jackson) is a wrong tool for parsing non-JSON structures.